# PHP - Access file outside web server

Tags: php, filesystems

I have FTP users which I have set up to be chrooted into a folder off the root of the server - e.x. user: myuser   homedir: /sftp/myuser/incoming. I would like to be able to access the files they FTP from a PHP script but can not figure out the path? Is it possible to access files in PHP outside of the "web server". I have seen many things online saying you can but cannot figure out the path. In the code below I am trying to access the csv file that has been sent to the server but I think the path is relative to the web server not the file system --

```
<?
$myFile = file_get_contents('/sftp/myuser/incoming/test.csv');
echo $myFile;
```

Comment: If you do not know the path, there's really no way to reference the file no matter what you're using.... how exactly does the process of their file being send to the site go?  Are they uploading it through a web page?  Are they uploading it via an FTP client to your server?

Comment: You can access files anywhere in the filesystem provided the PHP script has permissions there. With all filesystem access you need to work relative to the filesystem root, not the web server root. You'll have to determine the correct path to the ftp folders and what permissions you have there yourself - we can only guess. If you use an HTML form to upload the files you have complete control in PHP as to where the files go.

Comment: so if root owns the folder I am not going to be able to access it from the script? I am thinking I should just change their ftp directory to something inside the root of the site? For example if I link to an .jpg file and use an absolute path of /img/my.jpg that works, and I don't have to put in /etc/var/www... etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the FTP class for this.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Maybe use the ftp_get to get the file if you know the path.
Or recursively get all files in the user's folder.

Comment: The file is already sitting on the server. The client if FTPing the file to me, and then I am trying to read it.